# Is there a US and UK equivalent of India's AFSPA act?

Tags: united-states, law, united-kingdom, india, military-law

The Indian AFSPA (Armed Forces Special Protection Act) protects Indian soldiers from nuisance from humanitarian associations, among other benefits.

Is there any US and UK equivalent law for protecting their soldiers from such associations?

Answer (score 3):

No there is no such equivalent law.

In the USA it would probably be unconstitutional. In the UK it would likely contravene the Human Rights act.

There are laws that allow soldiers to kill on the battlefield, but not out of war zones. However, learn about the Bloody Sunday killings to see that it is possible for killings committed by soldiers to go unpunished.

Comment: British soldiers are still being hounded or tried for their actions in Ireland, N.Ireland, Afghanistan etc (Albeit unsuccessfully) e.g. case of Marine A. That alone should be enough evidence that at least officially UK doesn't provide any legal protections to soldiers accused of committing crimes on duty.

Comment: @NSNoob The case against Alexander Blackman (Marine A) wasn't unsuccessful. He is still convicted of manslaughter.

Comment: @Richard that's true. I personally believe the release after 3 years to be practically a failure (But that's of course my opinion which doesn't change the fact that he is convicted).

Comment: @NSNoob you mean the UK doesn't provide *additional* legal protections to soldiers accused of committing crimes on duty. They still have the rights that anyone else would, hence their anonymity during the trial.